# Coding transform files for existing web.configs (Reinventing the wheel?)

Tags: asp.net, web-config, transformation, web-config-transform, xdt-transform

I'm wondering why anyone (including myself) bothers to create insanely long and tedious xdt transforms for each key in a web.config file when one can simply put a "Replace" statement alongside the configuration declaration.

Let me explain with an example:

You are a developer that has been tasked to create a series of web.config transforms for a large web application.

You are given the web.configs for each environment and told to make:

- a base web.config that contains all keys and values common to each
  environment
- sets of transform files that contain all keys and values that differ from environment to environment

Here is a sample base web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="db.schema" value="app" />
    <add key="versionNumber" value="" />
    <add key="culture" value="en-US" />
    <add key="url" value="" />
    <add key="cache.Duration" value="0" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is a sample transform for the base web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<appSettings>
<add key="versionNumber"
     value="01.67.00"
     xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
<add key="url"
     value="http://thisIsNotAnActualURL.com"
     xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

Which outputs, as desired, the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="db.schema" value="app" />
    <add key="versionNumber" value="01.67.00" />
    <add key="culture" value="en-US" />
    <add key="url" value="http://thisIsNotAnActualURL.com" />
    <add key="cache.Duration" value="0" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is all fair and well but if you're a developer that's creating transforms based on massive web.configs that already exist wouldn't it be a lot easier to do the following as opposed to the above approach:

Base web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="Replace">
<appSettings>
    <add key="db.schema" value="app" />
    <add key="versionNumber" value="01.67.00" />
    <add key="culture" value="en-US" />
    <add key="url" value="http://thisIsNotAnActualURL.com" />
    <add key="cache.Duration" value="0" />
</appSettings>
```

The result is identical to the previous example, with far less work involved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="db.schema" value="app" />
    <add key="versionNumber" value="01.67.00" />
    <add key="culture" value="en-US" />
    <add key="url" value="http://thisIsNotAnActualURL.com" />
    <add key="cache.Duration" value="0" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I understand that by using this approach, when a change needs to occur in every environment, the change needs to be reflected in every transform; but apart from that, I can't see any drawback.

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious here, as I'm finding transforms that took me over 8 hours to code can be done in a matter of seconds with no apparent drawback

Comment: Why do you need more than one drawback? You've already identified that the duplication is an issue.

Comment: Because the way I'm doing it at the moment has several drawbacks, which I have also already identified

Comment: This may sounds a little stuffy but I personally prefer "nearly impossible to screw up silently" over "shorter". While I'm confident in my own ability to make sure all files are updated, I have no confidence in the new hire coming on board in 3 months time to baby sit the project not making a mistake. If one of those `add`s is typo'd out, a config file goes up with an unmodified value and nobody knows until the server starts doing something odd...

Comment: I'm not sure I properly understand what you mean, could you please explain why the "nearly impossible to screw up silently" method is nearly impossible to screw up silently?

If an add is 'typo'd out' in your preferred method how exactly would you be able to see the problem before it goes to the server? The value would still be unmodified after transform is applied

And furthermore, if an error exists in the web.config after it goes to the server then wouldn't there be two possible places to check for errors instead of one? (master and transform, as opposed to just transform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conjecture was the base of the advice I got here, we did decide on using "shorter" transformation method because of the following problems with the official method:

1. Takes longer to code
2. Takes longer to edit
3. Sharp learning curve for developers that have no experience with xdt
4. Increases code base without cutting on duplication